# Flutter Cupertino appbar hides screen space

Tags: ios, flutter

I have this annoying issue with the Cupertino widgets. When I create a super simple app setup (scaffold, navbar, one text item) the text seems to start far outside of the viewport.

heres the example:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
        navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
          middle: Text('Me Title'),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "No matter how short or long your journey to your accomplishment is, if you don't begin you can't get there. Beginning is difficult, but unavoidable!",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

which leads to [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXG0A.png).

The "native" Widgets (MaterialApp, Scaffold, AppBar) [lead to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG2KF.png) and work just fine:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Me Title'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "No matter how short or long your journey to your accomplishment is, if you don't begin you can't get there. Beginning is difficult, but unavoidable!",
```

Can somebody help out here? This is a bit annoying and I imagine this will f*** up every layout I try to build on it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

The solution that worked for me is wrapping the central `Column` into a `SafeArea` widget ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR9eK.jpg)):

```dart
    return CupertinoApp(
      home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
        navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
          middle: Text('Me Title'),
        ),

        // the SafeArea is new!
        child: SafeArea(

          // that's unchanged.
          child: Column(
            // ... etc.
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `SafeArea` widget for that. If you want to get only the height of top `SafeArea` you can use `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top` and apply it to padding/margin value.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to change the alignment of the child using MainAxisAlignment:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
        navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
          middle: Text('Me Title'),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "No matter how short or long your journey to your accomplishment is, if you don't begin you can't get there. Beginning is difficult, but unavoidable!",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```